# How do I get the development servlet of google app engine to find RestApiServlet?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets

I have an old Android project on which I use a Google app engine back-end.
After resuscitating the project I had to migrate to the V2.0 of the app engine, following https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/java/migrating

I had to do many changes and stumbled on several issue, some of which were fixed by following the recommendations here:
http://android.serverbox.ch/?p=1891&cpage=1#comment-146146

I am able to run the development server and use the web to open the endpoint page.
However when I run my application and it connects to the endpoint to write some data to file, I get the following error:

> Could not initialize class com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet
>
> #### Caused by:
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.google.api.server.spi.tools.devserver.RestApiServlet
>                                                                          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>                                                                          at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>                                                                          at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>                                                                          at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Holder.newInstance(Holder.java:153)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.initServlet(ServletHolder.java:428)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.getServlet(ServletHolder.java:339)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:487)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.api.socket.dev.DevSocketFilter.doFilter(DevSocketFilter.java:74)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.ResponseRewriterFilter.doFilter(ResponseRewriterFilter.java:134)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.HeaderVerificationFilter.doFilter(HeaderVerificationFilter.java:34)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.api.blobstore.dev.ServeBlobFilter.doFilter(ServeBlobFilter.java:63)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:48)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.StaticFileFilter.doFilter(StaticFileFilter.java:122)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:366)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doDirectModuleRequest(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:349)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerModulesFilter.doFilter(DevAppServerModulesFilter.java:116)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppEngineWebAppContext.handle(DevAppEngineWebAppContext.java:95)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>                                                                          at com.google.appengine.tools.development.JettyContainerService$ApiProxyHandler.handle(JettyContainerService.java:508)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   09-08 19:42:54.284 14926-15331/com.androdev.flightlog E/FlightLog:     at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnection.java:938)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:755)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>                                                                          at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)

It seems some library (jar) has not been loaded or the jetty server is not running the correct code.
I have found that the class it is looking for (RestApiServlet) appears in a jar in the gradle cache: appengine-local-endpoints-1.9.55.jar

How can I have that loaded? Or is there something else I need to do to re-configure the server?

PS: It may not be relevant, but this is all done under Android Studio. As such, Android Studio is supposed to help set things up, but my experience is that often it drives you to follow updates and leaves you in a broken state. This is such a situation. I had tagged this question with 'android-studio' but did not mention the fact that this is all under Android Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the Google page for migration has been updated. Going again through the instructions and making sure all my gradle files follow the updated instruction does fix the issue. Some changes in the backend gradle file as well as the web.xml file seem to have been the issue.

Comment: Thanks! One of the things they changed that I didn't notice is this line: `<url-pattern>/_ah/api/*</url-pattern>`. Now it is `api` instead of `spi`